# Elasticsearch Showing Result That Should Not Be Shown

Tags: elasticsearch

I have an elasticsearch index with this mapping.

```
{
    "hotels": {
        "mappings": {
            "properties": {
                "name": {
                    "type": "text"
                },
                "location": {
                    "type": "text"
                },
                "star": {
                    "type": "float"
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Inside the index, I put some documents. One of the document is something like this.

```
{
    "name": "Queens Hotel",
    "location": "West Australia",
    "star": 3.5
}
```

Then, I search for the document that match in the name and/or location field. The result should shown the match phrase on top of the one that only match a specific word. Therefore, I created this query.

```
{
    "query": {
        "bool": {
            "should": [
                {
                    "multi_match": {
                        "query": "queens loremipsum",
                        "type": "phrase",
                        "fields": [
                            "name",
                            "location"
                        ],
                        "boost": 10
                    }
                },
                {
                    "multi_match": {
                        "query": "queens loremipsum",
                        "type": "most_fields",
                        "fields": [
                            "name",
                            "location"
                        ],
                        "fuzziness": "AUTO"
                    }
                }
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

The query result shown the example data that I provided above. What I expect is that the `Queens Hotel` will not be shown in the result because in the query there is `loremipsum` that does not match the document. How to achieve that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The query result shown the example data that I provided above.

**This is because you are using bool with should clause in your search query, which acts like a logical OR operator. In your search query, there are two multi-match queries that are enclosed within the `should` clause. The document will return even if any one of the conditions given in the multi-match query is satisfied.**

Considering the multi-match query separately,

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "should": {
        "multi_match": {
          "query": "queens loremipsum",
          "type": "phrase",
          "fields": [
            "name",
            "location"
          ],
          "boost": 10
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

No search result are there

Considering the second multi-match query,

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "should": {
        "multi_match": {
          "query": "queens loremipsum",
          "type": "most_fields",
          "fields": [
            "name",
            "location"
          ],
          "fuzziness": "AUTO"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

**Search Result:**

```
"hits": [
      {
        "_index": "stof_64339433",
        "_type": "_doc",
        "_id": "1",
        "_score": 0.10536051,
        "_source": {
          "name": "Queens Hotel",
          "location": "West Australia",
          "star": 3.5
        }
      }
    ]
```

**So, the result is coming because of the second multi-match query, where you have added `type: most_fields` and even `"fuzziness": "AUTO"`**

Adding another index data, having the exact hotel name `queens loremipsum`

```
{
    "name": "queens loremipsum",
    "location": "West Australia",
    "star": 3.5
}
```

**Search Query:**

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "should": [
        {
          "multi_match": {
            "query": "queens loremipsum",
            "type": "phrase",
            "fields": [
              "name",
              "location"
            ],
            "boost": 10
          }
        },
        {
          "multi_match": {
            "query": "queens loremipsum",
            "type": "most_fields",
            "fields": [
              "name",
              "location"
            ],
            "fuzziness": "AUTO"
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

**Search Result:**

**Both the documents match (because of the `should` clause), but since in the first `multi_match` query with type `phrase`, `boost` is applied, therefore, this document has more score than the other document.**

```
"hits": [
      {
        "_index": "stof_64339433",
        "_type": "_doc",
        "_id": "2",
        "_score": 9.630155,              <-- note this
        "_source": {
          "name": "queens loremipsum",
          "location": "West Australia",
          "star": 3.5
        }
      },
      {
        "_index": "stof_64339433",
        "_type": "_doc",
        "_id": "1",
        "_score": 0.18232156,           <-- note this
        "_source": {
          "name": "Queens Hotel",
          "location": "West Australia",
          "star": 3.5
        }
      }
    ]
```

**NOTE: If you want only the exact document to match, then modify your search query as:**

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "multi_match": {
            "query": "queens loremipsum",
            "type": "phrase",
            "fields": [
              "name",
              "location"
            ],
            "boost": 10
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

**Update 1:**

Try out the below search query, you can change the fuzziness parameter, according to your use case

```
     {
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "should": [
        {
          "bool": {
            "must": {
              "multi_match": {
                "query": "queens australia",
                "type": "cross_fields",         <-- note this
                "operator": "and",
                "fields": [
                  "name",
                  "location"
                ],
                "boost": 10
              }
            }
          }
        },
        {
          "bool": {
            "must": [
              {
                "multi_match": {
                  "query": "queens",
                  "fields": [
                    "name",
                    "location"
                  ],
                  "fuzziness": "AUTO"
                }
              },
              {
                "multi_match": {
                  "query": "australia",
                  "fields": [
                    "name",
                    "location"
                  ],
                  "fuzziness": "AUTO"
                }
              }
            ]
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: however, I need the second query for typo tolerance. in summary, what i want to achieve in the query are as the following: first priority should be the one that match the phrase, could handle typo (in this case, I use fuzziness), when the phrase is totally different, it should not shown in the result.

Comment: @alcantula **when the phrase is totally different** means that the name is completely different ?

Comment: it is like the one that I mentioned in the question, like the name `Queens Hotel`, should not match with query `queens loremipsum`. even though it has the same word `queens`, but the next word is totally different with the name in the document, so it should not be shown.

Comment: @alcantula please go through my updated query and let me know if this resolved your issue ?

Comment: i tried the updated query. it works for the `queens loremipsum` case. however, it breaks another things, which is when what I search is `queens australia` it does not show any result even though `queens` is in the name and `australia` is in the location. and another one is i want the text query to be the same (in the updated answer, the second query is the token of the full search), since i want to use search template for this.

Comment: @alcantula please go through my updated query, you need to add `"type": "cross_fields"`, that looks for each word in any field. Regarding your second statement where you want the text query to be the same, I need to look into that. But as of now, according to me, the above query should work for all your searches. Can you please try the query, and let me know if you are getting the required results?

Comment: yes, adding `cross_fields` make the result is as expected. thank you for your answer!

Comment: @alcantula glad this worked for you  Can you please accept and upvote my answer as well 

Comment: sure, but i am still looking forward for how to make the second query as a single query